# How can I disable the View as grid/list buttons in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, view

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop.

On my category pages, I need to have the grid view only, without giving the customer the possibility of switching to the list view.

What is the easiest and/or the most appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can choose the Catalog view option as grid only or list only. The default is Grid/List. You can change it to List/Grid as well.

To do so:

1) Go to Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Storefront

2) Change the List Mode.

Answer (score 4):

If needed can be also applied from layout xml

catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="disableExpanded"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```